# weka java code kmeans clustering

Tags: java, weka

I write a java code for malware detection using datamining techniques (kmeans clustering). I use the jnetpcap library for sniffing packets to analyse it, then in the method `nextpacket` I write the kmeans clustering algorithm for the first packet.

The algorithm works well as it creates objects from class `Instances` with the specific attributes which will cluster based upon them, but on the next packet this code can't be run again as it throws an exception.

The code I'm using is this:

```
for(int dim = 0; dim < numDimensions; dim++)
{
    Attribute current = new Attribute("Attribute" + dim , dim);

    if(dim == 0)
    {
        for(int obj = 0; obj < numInstances; obj++)
        {
            // instances.add(new SparseInstance(numDimensions));
            instances.add(new DenseInstance(numDimensions) );
        }
    }

    for(int obj = 0; obj < numInstances; obj++)
    {
        instances.get(obj).setValue(current, (Double)data[dim+1][obj]);
    }

    atts.add(current);
}

Instances newDataset = new Instances("Dataset" , atts, instances.size());       //this is the line that throws the exception

for(Instance inst : instances)
    newDataset.add(inst);
SimpleKMeans kMeans = new SimpleKMeans();
kMeans.setNumClusters(2);
// kMeans.setMaxIterations(4);
kMeans.buildClusterer(newDataset);
//   int clusterNumbers;
// clusterNumbers=kMeans.numberOfClusters();
for (int j=0;j<numInstances;j++)
{ 
    int classif=kMeans.clusterInstance(newDataset.get(j));
    //  double []distr=kMeans.distributionForInstance(newDataset.firstInstance());
    System.out.println(classif);
    //   System.out.println(distr[0]);
    //  System.out.println(distr[1]);
    ArrayList<Double> temp5=flowFeatures.get((JFlowKey)data[0][j]);
    if (classif==0)
    {
        // instances0.add(newDataset.get(j));
         instance0FlowFeatures.put((JFlowKey)data[0][j], temp5);
    }
    else if(classif==1)
    {
        //instances1.add(newDataset.get(j));
        instance1FlowFeatures.put((JFlowKey)data[0][j], temp5);
    }
}
```

And the exception I'm seeing is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute names are not unique! Causes: 'Attribute0' 'Attribute1' 'Attribute2' 'Attribute3' 'Attribute4' 'Attribute5' 'Attribute6' 'Attribute7' 'Attribute0' 'Attribute1' 'Attribute2' 'Attribute3' 'Attribute4' 'Attribute5' 'Attribute6' 'Attribute7'
```

Could anyone please help me, please?

Comment: Where is `atts` declared? Do you clear it out or create a new instance every time? If you don't, you'll have duplicate attributes added to the `atts` every time you go through that first for-loop.

Comment: How could I clear the atts out?

Answer (score 0):

Think attributes like table's columns and has to be created once.

Here is the code for single dimensional data.
In this example my imaginary table has one column as "attr1" and table has 
3 records(instances) in it, keeping very simple to understand the structure.

```
        Attribute attr1 = new Attribute("attr1");                               
        ArrayList<Attribute> attrList = new ArrayList<Attribute>();             
        attrList.add(attr1);                

        Instances dataset = new Instances("test", attrList, 0);

        double[] val1 = new double[] { 1.2};
        double[] val2 = new double[] { 2.2};
        double[] val3 = new double[] { 1.4};

        Instance instance0 = new DenseInstance(1.0, val1);
        instance0.setDataset(dataset);

        Instance instance1 = new DenseInstance(1.0, val2);
        instance1.setDataset(dataset);

        Instance instance2 = new DenseInstance(1.0, val3);
        instance2.setDataset(dataset);

        dataset.add(instance0);     
        dataset.add(instance1); 
        dataset.add(instance2); 

        SimpleKMeans kmeans = new SimpleKMeans();               
        try {
            kmeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);
            kmeans.setNumClusters(2);
            kmeans.setSeed(2);
            kmeans.setDontReplaceMissingValues(true);
            kmeans.buildClusterer(dataset);
            kmeans.setMaxIterations(10);                                    
            Instances instances = kmeans.getClusterCentroids();
            int assignments[] = kmeans.getAssignments();
            int x=0;
            for(int assignment : assignments) {
                System.out.println("data :" + dataset.get(x) + "instance idx: " + x + " centroid value: " + instances.get(assignment));
                x++;
            }
         }
```